# Angular 2 material MdExpansionModule - Lazy load content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `MdExpansionModule` of angular material, i like to load the content when user expands a accordian menu. There is a documentation on lazy rendering with `mat-expansion-panel`:

https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Example :

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    This is the expansion title
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <ng-template **matExpansionPanelContent**>
    Some deferred content
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I am using older version of `md`, this is the code that i have tried :

```
<md-accordion class="">
        <md-expansion-panel *ngFor="data">
            <md-expansion-panel-header>
                <md-panel-title>
                    title                       
                </md-panel-title>
                <md-panel-description>
                    desc
                </md-panel-description>
            </md-expansion-panel-header>

            <ng-template **mdExpansionPanelContent**>
                <other-component [data]="data"></other-component>
            </ng-template>
        </md-expansion-panel>
    </md-accordion>
```

I replaced `matExpansionPanelContent` to `mdExpansionPanelContent`, now the content is not loaded when menu is created, but its not getting loaded when i expand a menu part.

**Edit:** If this is not supported in older version, is there a way to implement it manually. The panels are created in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure that an MdExpansionPanelContent directive was never implemented prior to v5 as MatExpansionPanelContent.